# Git log `--first-parent`, WITH just the first merged commit from the second parent

Tags: git, merge, version-control

## Background

I love `git log --first-parent`, especially when used in combination with `--one-line`. So much so, that I alias it to `lgp`:

```
log --graph --abbrev-commit --decorate --format=format:'%C(yellow)%h%C(reset) %C(normal)%s%C(reset) %C(dim white)%an%C(reset) %C(dim blue)(%ar)%C(reset) %C(auto)%d%C(reset)' --first-parent
```

which gives me output that looks like this:

```
$ git lgp -5
* 041f5ea1cf The third batch Junio C Hamano (2 weeks ago)  (HEAD -> master, origin/master, origin/HEAD)
* 0c45fa32ec Merge branch 'br/commit-tree-parseopt' Junio C Hamano (2 weeks ago) 
* f6c75e392e Merge branch 'jk/config-type-color-ends-with-lf' Junio C Hamano (2 weeks ago) 
* 6b5688b760 Merge branch 'ma/clear-repository-format' Junio C Hamano (2 weeks ago) 
* 83b13e284c Merge branch 'jk/virtual-objects-do-exist' Junio C Hamano (2 weeks ago)
```

This output is from the `git.git` repository, which uses a [clever branch and merge strategy](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitworkflows#_managing_branches). With this approach, `--first-parent` allows displaying a clean history, with all of the detail of each merged topic (feature branch) elided, but available if needed. For example, to see all of the commits that where merged from `jk/virtual-objects-do-exist`, run this:

```
git mergedtopiclg 83b13e284c
* f06ab027ef rev-list: allow cached objects in existence check Jeff King (5 weeks ago)  (origin/jk/virtual-objects-do-exist)
* 7c0fe330d5 rev-list: handle missing tree objects properly Matthew DeVore (6 months ago) 
* f1d02daacf list-objects: always parse trees gently Matthew DeVore (8 months ago) 
* 9202489174 list-objects: refactor to process_tree_contents Matthew DeVore (8 months ago) 
* f447a499db list-objects: store common func args in struct Matthew DeVore (8 months ago)
```

`mergedtopiclg` is the following alias, or actually pair of aliases (feel free to provide simplifications or improvements to these as well, as I am not completely happy with how complex these are, for bonus upvotes!):

```
oldest-ancestor = !bash -c 'diff --old-line-format= --new-line-format= <(git rev-list --first-parent \"${1:-master}\") <(git rev-list --first-parent \"${2:-HEAD}\") | head -1' -
mergedtopiclg = !sh -c \"git lg $(git oldest-ancestor $1^2 ${2:-master})..$1^2\" -
```

## And Finally, the Question

Now, sometimes however, I'd love to use `--first-parent`, but show just the first commit from the *second* parent, which tells me *exactly what* commit was actually merged in, without having to look at all the parents of that commit. So, what I want is an alias `lgpp` that will give me this output:

```
$ git lgpp -5
* 041f5ea1cf The third batch Junio C Hamano (2 weeks ago)  (HEAD -> master, origin/master, origin/HEAD)
(4 weeks ago)  (origin/br/commit-tree-parseopt)
* 0c45fa32ec Merge branch 'br/commit-tree-parseopt' Junio C Hamano (2 weeks ago) 
|\  
| * cbdeab98e8 commit-tree: utilize parse-options api Brandon Richardson * f6c75e392e Merge branch 'jk/config-type-color-ends-with-lf' Junio C Hamano (2 weeks ago) 
* f6c75e392e Merge branch 'jk/config-type-color-ends-with-lf' Junio C Hamano (2 weeks ago) 
|\  
| * cd8e7593b9 config: document --type=color output is a complete line Jeff King (4 weeks ago)  (origin/jk/config-type-color-ends-with-lf)
* 6b5688b760 Merge branch 'ma/clear-repository-format' Junio C Hamano (2 weeks ago) 
|\  
| * e8805af1c3 setup: fix memory leaks with `struct repository_format` Martin Ågren (5 weeks ago)  (origin/ma/clear-repository-format)
* 83b13e284c Merge branch 'jk/virtual-objects-do-exist' Junio C Hamano (2 weeks ago)
|\  
| * f06ab027ef rev-list: allow cached objects in existence check Jeff King (5 weeks ago)  (origin/jk/virtual-objects-do-exist)
```

Clone `git.git` and rewind master to 041f5ea1cf987a4068ef5f39ba0a09be85952064 to replicate the output given in the commands above.

Answer (score 3):

Here's how to do the last 20 mainline commits and the tip of any merged branches:

```
git rev-list --first-parent  --parents HEAD \
| awk '{ for (i=2; i<NF; ) print $++i }' >.git/info/grafts

git log --graph --decorate --oneline @~20..

rm .git/info/grafts
```

the `awk` makes a line for all second-or-greater parents of the mainline commits for the grafts file, a list of local-only ancestry rewrites specifically for cases where the recorded ancestry doesn't serve the immediate purpose. "It looks stupid, but it works."

```
$ git log --graph --decorate --oneline @~20..
* d638ded169 (HEAD -> master) options
* 041f5ea1cf (origin/master, origin/HEAD) The third batch
*   0c45fa32ec Merge branch 'br/commit-tree-parseopt'
|\
| * cbdeab98e8 (grafted) commit-tree: utilize parse-options api
*   f6c75e392e Merge branch 'jk/config-type-color-ends-with-lf'
|\
| * cd8e7593b9 (grafted) config: document --type=color output is a complete line
*   6b5688b760 Merge branch 'ma/clear-repository-format'
|\
| * e8805af1c3 (grafted) setup: fix memory leaks with `struct repository_format`
*   83b13e284c Merge branch 'jk/virtual-objects-do-exist'
|\
| * f06ab027ef (grafted) rev-list: allow cached objects in existence check
*   27cdbdd134 Merge branch 'jk/no-sigpipe-during-network-transport'
|\
| * 143588949c (grafted) fetch: ignore SIGPIPE during network operation
*   ea327760d3 Merge branch 'jk/fsck-doc'
|\
| * 8d8c2a5aef (grafted) fsck: always compute USED flags for unreachable objects
*   88255bba45 Merge branch 'js/stress-test-ui-tweak'
|\
| * f545737144 (grafted) tests: introduce --stress-jobs=<N>
*   9fbcc3d203 Merge branch 'js/rebase-orig-head-fix'
|\
| * cbd29ead92 (grafted) built-in rebase: set ORIG_HEAD just once, before the rebase
*   1b8f4dc580 Merge branch 'jk/bisect-final-output'
|\
| * b02be8b901 (grafted) bisect: make diff-tree output prettier
*   3cef67694c Merge branch 'ab/makefile-help-devs-more'
|\
| * 6d5d4b4e93 (grafted) Makefile: allow for combining DEVELOPER=1 and CFLAGS="..."
*   0e94f7aa73 Merge git://ozlabs.org/~paulus/gitk
|\
| * dec59817c1 (grafted) gitk: Update Bulgarian translation (317t)
* e902e9bcae The second batch
*   be9f1c0224 Sync with maint
|\
| * aeb582a983 (grafted, origin/maint) mingw: allow building with an MSYS2 runtime v3.x
*   a07baf33e3 Merge branch 'js/rebase-recreate-merge'
|\
| * dbf47215e3 (grafted) rebase docs: fix "gitlink" typo
*   d61ddb5189 Merge branch 'js/untravis-windows'
|\
| * 50b206371d (grafted) travis: remove the hack to build the Windows job on Azure Pipelines
*   443442ec71 Merge branch 'rd/gc-prune-doc-fix'
|\
| * 716a5af812 (grafted) docs/git-gc: fix typo "--prune=all" to "--prune=now"
*   c0d97d299e Merge branch 'js/find-lib-h-with-ls-files-when-possible'
|\
| * 92b88eba9f (grafted) Makefile: use `git ls-files` to list header files, if possible
* 1de413bc1d Merge branch 'rj/hdr-check-gcrypt-fix'
```

Answer (score 0):

Git doesn't have an option to do specifically what you want. This is commonly requested, but it isn't implemented (and it's not likely to be upstream).

`--topo-order` will do something very similar to what you want if you have single-commit branches, because it will prevent interspersing the commits on the branches with other branches. If you have multiple-commit branches, then there isn't an option to do what you're requesting.